Delete blank page after table in Word

I get these weird circle symbols that I can't seem to delete (or select):

Before the page with the xxxxx and yyyyy is a page with a table, if that is of any relevance.
How can I get rid of this weird circle symbol and thus delete the redundant page at the very end of my document?

If you turned on display of non-printing formatting characters and table gridlines you would see that the circle character is a marker for end of a table cell. You have an extra row or extra space in the row.
You can see the paragraph markers showing blank or empty paragraphs, which are seldom a good idea.
Here is a link to my chapter on Tables in Word. https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/tables.htm
Often tables can cause an empty blank page when at the end of a document. This can be because of the paragraph which must follow a table. Sometimes, it works to select this paragraph and change the font size to 1.

Turns out my table was too long. I had to delete some text at the end of the table (even though it seemed to fit!) and then resize the table to make it smaller. If you can't find your table edge, you can turn on borders.
